# Flipping RGBA output of glReadPixels (C++ OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to flip the output image from glReadPixel. I have checked the output from glReadPixels by saving it to a file. The image is correct, however its upside down.

**What I tried**

```
int patchSize = 50;
std::vector<unsigned char> rgbdata(4*patchSize*patchSize);
glReadPixels(x-(patchSize/2), y-(patchSize/2)/2), patchSize,patchSize,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &rgbdata[0]);

std::vector< unsigned char > temp_rgbdata = rgbdata; // Create a copy of the data
    rgbdata.clear(); // Reset the array
    for (int i=patchSize-1; i >= 0; i--) // Count backwards in order to flip
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < patchSize; j++) {

            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[i*patchSize+j*4]);
            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[i*patchSize+j*4+1]);
            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[i*patchSize+j*4+2]);
            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[i*patchSize+j*4+3]);

        }
    }
    temp_rgbdata.clear(); // Clear the temporary array
```

**What is wrong**

The images turns out all wrong:

[image: Output from trying to flip image]

Any help and comments are appreciated. Thank you.

**Solution (by Boris)**

```
int patchSize = 50;
std::vector<unsigned char> rgbdata(4*patchSize*patchSize);
glReadPixels(x-(patchSize/2), y-(patchSize/2)), patchSize,patchSize,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &rgbdata[0]);

std::vector< unsigned char > temp_rgbdata = rgbdata; // Create a copy of the data
    rgbdata.clear(); // Reset the array
    for (int i=patchSize-1; i >= 0; i--) // Count backwards in order to flip
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < patchSize; j++) {

            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[(i*patchSize+j)*4]);
            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[(i*patchSize+j)*4+1]);
            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[(i*patchSize+j)*4+2]);
            rgbdata.push_back(temp_rgbdata[(i*patchSize+j)*4+3]);

        }
    }
    temp_rgbdata.clear(); // Clear the temporary array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses in all those lines:

```
temp_rgbdata[ (i*patchSize+j)*4 ]
```

By the way, you can be much more efficient by:

1. Getting the upside down image into the temporary array (avoid a useless copy)
2. Initialize rgbdata of final size and copy a whole line at once:

Here is how you would do:

```
int patchSize = 50;
std::vector<unsigned char> temp_rgbdata(4*patchSize*patchSize);
glReadPixels(x-(patchSize/2), y-(patchSize/2)),patchSize,patchSize,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &temp_rgbdata[0]);

std::vector< unsigned char > rgbdata(4*patchSize*patchSize);
for (int i=0; i < patchSize; i++) // Doesn't matter the order now
    memcpy(&rgbdata[i*patchSize*4],                    // address of destination
           &temp_rgbdata[(patchSize-i-1)*patchSize*4], // address of source
           patchSize*4*sizeof(unsigned char) );        // number of bytes to copy

temp_rgbdata.clear(); // Clear the temporary array
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example, built ontop of Stypox's great snippet - this does the actual writing also. Of course, swapping your co-ord system is another workaround
but I find 0,0 at the top left more natural.

```
// https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h
#include "stb_image_write.h"

glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);

std::vector<uint8_t> pixels(3 * w * h);
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data());

for(int line = 0; line != h/2; ++line) {
    std::swap_ranges(pixels.begin() + 3 * w * line,
                     pixels.begin() + 3 * w * (line+1),
                     pixels.begin() + 3 * w * (h-line-1));
}

int components = 3;
stbi_write_png("out.png", w, h, components, pixels.data(), 3 * w);
stbi_write_tga("out.tga", w, h, components, pixels.data());
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're reading and writing from/to the correct coordinate system? The following is taken from [OpenGL.org](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/):

> Another common pitfall related to 2D rendering APIs having an upper left-hand coordinate system is that 2D image file formats start the image at the top scan line, not the bottom scan line. OpenGL assumes images start at the bottom scan line by default. If you do need to flip an image when rendering, you can use
>   glPixelZoom(1,-1).

If your saved image is always appearing upside down, this is probably what's going wrong. Make sure you know where your (0,0) pixel is (upper left or lower left) and then adjust your image alrogithm(s) accordingly.

Comment: +1 It doesn't answer why the flip code didn't work, but remove the need to flip in the first place ;-)

Comment: In fact, glPixelZoom do not work with glRead, only glWrite, and is deprecated anyway. So the +1 is just for the idea: trying to get the image not upside down is the best strategy.

Comment: Good point. I actually posted a question a few weeks ago, where I had the same problem. My textures on the objects where upside down. I solved it by flipping the image in the vertex shader, however the problem now cumulates so I should properbly find a way to change the image when loaded.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to flip the output of `glReadPixels` without temporary vectors using C++17 [`swap_ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges). The code below is not specific to what was asked, and can be used with any values of `x`, `y`, `w` and `h`.

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> pixels(3 * w * h);
glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data());

for(int line = 0; line != h/2; ++line) {
    std::swap_ranges(
            pixels.begin() + 3 * w * line,
            pixels.begin() + 3 * w * (line+1),
            pixels.begin() + 3 * w * (h-line-1));
}
```

Comment: Great answer! And if you add just 2 more lines then you get it written out to disk nicely too. #include "stb_image_write.h" stbi_write_png("out.png", w, h, 3, pixels.data(), 3 * w); from https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h

Answer (score 0):

I use this sentence to capture the screen,

```c
glReadPixels(0,0,SCR_WIDTH,SCR_HEIGHT,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buf);
```

and the buf's type is uint8_t*,

so I do it like this

```c
void flip(uint8_t** buf)
{
    int totalLength = SCR_HEIGHT*SCR_WIDTH*3;
    int oneLineLength = SCR_WIDTH*3;
    uint8_t* tmp = (uint8_t*)malloc(SCR_HEIGHT*SCR_WIDTH*3);
    memcpy(tmp,*buf,SCR_WIDTH*SCR_HEIGHT*3);
    memset(*buf,0,sizeof(uint8_t)*SCR_HEIGHT*SCR_WIDTH*3);
    for(int i = 0; i < SCR_HEIGHT;i++){
        memcpy(*buf+oneLineLength*i,tmp+totalLength-oneLineLength*(i+1),oneLineLength);
    }
  
}
```